# Why Gephi hides most of edges on graph?

Tags: graph, graph-theory, gephi, edge-list

I have a csv file with graph formatted as edge list, ie Source, Target, Label, Type (Directed), Weight (all weights = 1)
It consist of 31900 edges as i checked in Data laboratory.
Then i go to view my graph and in the Context (right top corner of Gephi) i see:
Nodes: 1869
Edges: 3160

Why number of edges is not 31900, why it's 10 times smaller??

My guess Gephi somehow reduce this number, because if i compute Average weighted degree it shows 17, so if i multiply 1869 * 17,01 = 31959 - exactly the number of edges.
So where that edges on graph?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Edge is a connection of nodes, so edges are equal(same) when its source and target is same. Though your data consist of 31900 edges, maybe there're many identical edge, I guess.

To validate this hypothesis, you can calculate the `weight` and you would see the edge now won't be 1 anymore. And the sum of the edge's weight are still 31900.